# Using POST request for deleting or getting data

Tags: rest, http, web, request

How bad is to use POST operation for deleting entity or getting entity?

In my context, I'm creating an api, where there is a request which requires a device MAC address and a username. This request deletes the device from the user.

Next request requires a device MAC address, and a secret key to get data about the device.

I want to have these requests secure and don't want to show arguments in request address, because these data are quite private, so I want to use POST operation.

Is it very bad, only bed, normal, ok, good solution...? Thank you.

Comment: POST methods aren't secure because you can get data from the request body. If you want to secure your request, you have to encrypt your parameters.

Comment: @SébastienTemprado I meant the "secure" that it is not in url. But still I would like to know how bad is use POST for this purposes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it mandatory to use appropiate Method Types (POST , PUT , GET , DELETE) using REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820843/is-it-mandatory-to-use-appropiate-method-types-post-put-get-delete-using)